# Count of numbers above a value, count of numbers below a value, and total count of numbers

Tags: reporting-services, count

This is for an SSRS report, I don't have access to the SQL so I need to know if this can be done in SSRS. I have several hundred ages that belong to groups, I need a count of adult and juveniles in each group.
Ex:

```
Blue    30
Blue    12
Black   50
Orange  17
```

Results would be:

```
         Adult  Juvenile
Blue       1       1
Black      1       0
Orange     0       1
```

I currently have `=COUNT(IIF(Fields!RptAge.Value>=18,1,Nothing))` and `=SUM(COUNT(IIF(Fields!RptAge.Value>=18,1,Nothing)))`, but both show a 1 on each group no matter the actual count. I have tried several others as well, but the results are no better. I have Googled for a couple hours but am having no luck. Help!

Comment: You don't want 18 in both groups so you should only use one = , you have to decide which group an 18 year old sits in, but make sure the counting is "mutually exclusive" e.g. `COUNT(IIF(Fields!RptAge.Value<18,1,Nothing))` and `COUNT(IIF(Fields!RptAge.Value>=18,1,Nothing))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM rather than count (which will count everything regardless of the result of your IIF).

e.g.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!RptAge.Value>=18,1,0))
```

and

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!RptAge.Value<18,1,0))
```

**OR**

set the column group to group on an expression ..

```
=IIF(Fields!RptAge.Value>=18,"Adult","Juvenile")
```

and the cell value will just be

```
=CountRows()
```

Comment: This is what I am getting using the formulas:
[Screen shot of partial results][1]
The final totals are correct, so you can see that each row should have totals over 1. For these examples, the count of adults should = the total, but I am only getting 1 and the same thing happens for juveniles. I've tried different methods, but none give the expected or needed results.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/93XFe.png

Comment: edit your question, show your current report layout  including all expressions, row groups, column groups etc. This should be simple

Answer (score 0):

There was apparently a glitch in the report that was causing the fields to not work correctly. I rebuilt the report from scratch and used =SUM(COUNT(IIF(Fields!RptAge.Value >= 18, 1, Nothing))) and =SUM(COUNT(IIF(Fields!RptAge.Value < 18, 1, Nothing))) (with the spaces) and it worked correctly. Thanks for the assistance!